# Improve code format (performance)

Tags: java, android, textview

I try to format my code to gain the best performance and avoid memory leak and delay of operation of my app, one of activity dealing with multiple textview created programmatically (40 textview paragraph separated by separator) .

and as my little Knowledge of android development i reach to below code, all textview has same text color, same text size and same custom font and gravity but they **different in string only** which customized by html tags in string xml .

as below code:

**Is there is better construction code formatting to gain same purpose**?

```
public class Text extends Activity {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);      setContentView(R.layout.text);  
     if (customTitleSupported) { getWindow().setFeatureInt
           (Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title); }

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_tv1); 
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
    tv.setTypeface(face);
    tv.setText(" My Text ");  


    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv1.setTextSize(30);    
        tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        ll.addView(tv1);
        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text1)));  

        ImageView divider1 = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp1.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        divider1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);      
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv2.setTextSize(30);
        tv2.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        ll.addView(tv2);
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.TEXT2)));

        ImageView divider2 = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp2.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider2.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        divider2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider2);

        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv3.setTextSize(30);
        tv3.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        ll.addView(tv3);
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.TEXT3)));

        ImageView divider3 = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp3.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider3.setLayoutParams(lp3);
        divider3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider3);

        TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
        tv4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv4.setTextSize(30);    
        tv4.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        ll.addView(tv4);
        tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.TEXT4)));  

        ImageView divider4 = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp4 = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp4.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider4.setLayoutParams(lp4);
        divider4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider4);
```

**and this will continue in the same manner till textview tv40 .**

Adding custom font as bellow :

```
    public static class FontFactory {

            private static Typeface t1;

            public static Typeface getBFantezy(Context c) {
                if (t1 == null) {
                    t1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf");
                }
                return t1;
            }}

            }
```

**UPDATE:** 
I try to did it this way but i had force close :

**MainActivity:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] paragraphs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paragraphs);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    addParagraphs(layout, paragraphs);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);}

private void addParagraphs(LinearLayout layout, String[] paragraphs) {
    for (String paragraph : paragraphs) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(30);   
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        tv.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        layout.addView(tv);
        tv.setText(paragraph);  

        ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider.setLayoutParams(params);
        divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        layout.addView(divider); } 
                                }
                            }
```

**FontFactory:**

```
public class FontFactory {

private static Typeface t1;

public static Typeface getBFantezy(Context c) {
    if (t1 == null) {
        t1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf");
    }
    return t1;
}}
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
ComponentInfo{com.test.demo/com.test.demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.demo.MainActivity.addParagraphs(MainActivity.java:29)
at com.test.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

Comment: How about lists and loops?

Comment: @jlordo please can you explain with piece of code , thanks

Comment: I see you have subtle changes on every TextView. This won't be so easy.

Comment: @jlordo so no othe approach

Comment: Code formatting doesn't improve performance.

Comment: @EJP before this code i instiate all texview in xml when run activity there was delay in oping that activity but with this going better , this what i mean my dear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this using `TextView` with `ImageView` as dividers, you can first create a string array of paragraphs.

Put this in your `/res/values/arrays.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="paragraphs">
        <item>Paragraph 1 content here</item>
        <item>Paragraph 2 content here</item>
        <item>Paragraph 3 content here</item>
<!-- And so on until how many paragraphs you like -->
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then you can get these paragraphs in your code like so:

```
String[] paragraphs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paragraphs);
```

Then you can use a method like this:

```
private void addParagraphs(LinearLayout layout, String[] paragraphs) {
    for (String paragraph : paragraphs) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(30);    
        tv.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        layout.addView(tv);
        tv.setText(paragraph);  

        ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider.setLayoutParams(params);
        divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        layout.addView(divider);
    }
}
```

To complete the example, you can populate your layout with the paragraphs like this:

```
String[] paragraphs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paragraphs);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
addParagraphs(layout, paragraphs);
```

Edit: If you want to set other paragraph parameters like alignment, you can create another string array on `res/values/arrays.xml` with the same number of items as the paragraphs string array, then pass them on the method to set the alignments respective to each paragraph number. There are more ways to do it, this is just one example. Get creative and enjoy. :)

Comment: please my dear would you please check update related to your answer , thanks

Comment: You should call setContentView(R.layout.main) after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) and before defining your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend that you consider using a `ListView` so that you don't have to create each of these items individually. Also, I don't know what your implementation of `FontFactory` is, but create the font only once if possible.

Comment: @androidqq6 Your `FontFactory` looks fine, more or less, but do think about using a `ListView`.